# getConfiguration().orientation doesn't work in Android Fragment

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation, device-orientation

I try to get the screen **orientation** in an **Android Fragment** using *getResources().getConfiguration().orientation* but it returns the same result even though I rotated the device in portrait and landscape mode. I also used in in onConfigurationChanged() (see code below) and the configuration received as parameter reports the corect screen orientation but the generic method of getting the screen orientation always reports the same orientation mode in which the activity started(either landscape or portrait).

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Log.e(TAG, "NEW CONFIG: ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "NEW CONFIG: ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");

    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        Log.e(TAG, "config: PORTRAIT");
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "config: LANDSCAPE");


    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    populateViewForOrientation(inflater, (ViewGroup)getView());
}
```

For example if the activity started in landsape mode the first log output will be:

1.a "NEW CONFIG: ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE"

1.b "config: LANDSCAPE"

**after I rotate the device in portrait mode:**

2.a "NEW CONFIG: ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT"

2.b "config: LANDSCAPE"

As you can notice, the config reports the same orientation mode even though the device has different orientation mode.

So what is happening here? Thank you! :)

Comment: It is working fine on my case, can you please move the second IF to onCreate function and see what happens?

Comment: If I move it in onCreateView(...) it works. But as I mentioned in the question. The first call of the method returns the correct orientation(like in onCreateView) but after I change the orientation and onConfigurationChanged(...) is called the method reports the same orientation mode even thought the orientation is changed

Answer (score 1):

Some times the easy solution is not to fight the system and just to accept the facts as they are. Just update the configuration as they change.

Try this:

```
private Configuration configuration;

private int getOrientation(){
    return getConfiguration().orientation;
}

private Configuration getConfiguration(){
    if (configuration == null) {
        configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    }
    return configuration;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    configuration = newConfig;
}
```